# Variables in selector when converting .live() to .on()

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to modernize some code that uses the deprecated .live() function. However one call uses a variable in the selector, and I am not sure how to properly translate this to .on() syntax. The deprecated code is:

```
    $('.selector .item a', $cal_fields).live('click', function(){
        //do stuff
    });
```

And my initial (failed) attempt to convert it to .on() was:

```
$('body').on('click','.selector .item a, '+$cal_fields, function()
```

The $cal_fields variable is given an initial assignment of

```
var $cal_fields     = $('#calendar_fields');
```

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, you'll need *emulate* just what `.live()` is doing.  When you call `.live()`, what's *actually* happening is that jQuery is binding the event to the `document` and then checking to see if `event.target` matches your selector.

One other issue is with your `$cal_fields` variable.  Since `#calendar_fields` (probably) doesn't exist when the page is loaded, we'll need to re-evaluate that selector each time, to get the elements.

So, you can try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click', $cal_fields.selector+' .selector .item a', function(){
});
```

`$cal_fields.selector` will return you the string used to make that jQuery object (the selector).

Also, `$('.selector .item a', $cal_fields)` is just shorthand for `$cal_fields.find('.selector .item a')`, so `'#calendar_fields .selector .item a'` should be equivalent.